# Indesign Threaded Frames - Applying Different styles to the frames

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, paragraph-styles

Using InDesign CC,

is there a way to make two or more threaded frames have different paragraph styles applied to them? What I need is to paste a text on the first frame, and when text flows to the next threaded frame, it should get a different style applied to it (in my specific case, the color and typeface need to change from frame to frame)
Thanks

Comment: I'm nearly certain there is no option in InDesign to achieve this. However, you may be able to utilize Nested Styles to accomplish a similar affect. Is there a marker (hyphen, line break) of any kind in your text to indicate when the style change should happen? Maybe check [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/indesign-resetting-character-style-after-end-of-paragraph/15868)?

Comment: Wow, I had never heard of Nested Styles, and there might be a way to make it work this way. I'm studying it now, will comment back soon. Thanks for the workaround

Comment: The question I referenced uses GREP styles, which may be more complex than what you need. Using Nested Styles instead may be easier since you can select markers from a pull-down, or even specify X lines for this style, and so on. Here is a [sample](http://i.imgur.com/nGi9HYo.png).

Answer (score 1):

InDesign's Paragraph Styles are a text attribute, not a frame attribute, so the applied Paragraph Style dominates. Even if you specify different Object Styles for different frames, and set different Paragraph Styles for each, it's the last Paragraph Style of the first threaded frame that takes precedence.

Think this through, and you'll see the logic. You can't change the style of a paragraph half-way through the paragraph. If a paragraph were to span two text frames with different Object Styles applied, that's exactly what your scenario would require.

As an exercise, create two text frames on the same page and fill each with placeholder text, using a different paragraph style for each frame. Give each frame its own Object Style, specifying one paragraph style to the first frame, another to the second. Now thread them. That should make it clear what's occurring.

In essence, an Object Style can force a Paragraph Style only if the frame is not threaded, and only if a Paragraph Style has not been explicitly applied.

Comment: I've noticed this, so regrettably the answer to my question is a big "No No" then, from this perspective